# Как убрать ошибку RuntimeException

Tags: java, исключения, switch, калькулятор, runtime

Как ошибку Рантайм  сделать нормальной?

```
public class Calculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int result;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("КАЛЬКУЛЯТОР");
        System.out.println("Введите первое число");

        int n1 = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Введите второе число");
        int n2 = scanner.nextInt();


        System.out.println("Введите операцию");
        String operation = scanner.next();


        switch (operation) {
            case "+":
                result = n1 + n2;
                break;
            case "-":
                result = n1 - n2;
                break;
            case "*":
                result = n1 * n2;
                break;
            case "/":
                result = n1 / n2;
                break;
            default:
                
                throw new IllegalStateException("Не математическая операция: " + operation); //тут
        }
        System.out.println("Результат операции:");
        System.out.println(result);

    }
}
```

Comment: Замените на  `sout` и не забудьте считать конец строки (`scanner.nextLine() `)

Comment: Нужно уточнить все же ваш вопрос. Просто в теле программы вы сами кидаете исключение. И из вопроса следует, что вы его кидать не хотите, верно? Или у вас все же появляется какое-то другое исключение кроме "не математическая операция" и вы хотите убрать его??

Answer (score 0):

```java
try {
    int n1 = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Введите второе число");int n2 = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Введите операцию");
    String operation = scanner.next();
} catch (RuntimeException) {

}
```